# How to send complex objectfrom view to controller using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my view i`m having various ul each containing various li and each li contains a textbox, in which the user enters information.

```
<ul id="ul1"><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li></ul>

<ul id="ul2"><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li></ul>
```

I also have a table which has 2 columns and various rows.  Each column contains a textbox.

My question is as follows:
1.  How do I retrieve the values separately [each ul separately and table data]and send them to the controller using ajax?

Comment: this is some really basic jquery-stuff you are asking. Smells a bit like *plz-send*. I suggest you take a closer look at Jquery yourself.

Comment: jQuery is great but you don't need it everywhere. MVC has a way to do this without js, its just a simple http post guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this was a pain for me too. So this is how you can do it. Everything in html needs a unique id but interestingly mvc controller will also que in on the name first. So if you give them all a name of "mytextareaarray" or something like that and put in a variable in the actionmethod called string[] mytextareaarray it should work just fine. Here is how it would look:

```
<ul id="ul1"><li><input name="mytextareaarray"  type="text"></li><li><input name="mytextareaarray" type="text"></li></ul> 

<ul id="ul2"><li><input name="mytextareaarray"  type="text"></li><li><input name="mytextareaarray"  type="text"></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To post all variable , use jquery $.ajax method

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "yourcontroller URL",
                    cache: false,               
                    data: $('#youformname').serialize(),
                    success: function(json){

                    },
});
```

Comment: How do i retrieve them in the controller?

Comment: @user269431: depends on the technology you are using serverside, and I REALLY suggest to do some research yourself 'cause you're missing a lot of basic knowledge

Comment: String userName = request.getParameter("userName"); 

where userName is your view form input field